# is it possible to dynamically register servlets from a javaagent?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, servlet-3.0, javaagents

I have a java agent with a class annotated with `@WebServlet`. I am attaching this agent to a servlet-based application using Servlet 3.0, by specifying the `-javaagent:/path/to/agent/jar` in `JAVA_OPTS`.

Yet, the servlet doesn't appear to be loaded and I get 404 error when trying to access the servlet.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It depends on how your Servlet container discovers servlets. What is your servlet container?

Comment: The webapp runs in a tomcat servlet container, @tair.

Comment: Also using `@WebServlet` is not the ultimate way of doing it, because a web-app may be declared as `metadata-complete`, so Tomcat won't scan any libs for servlets, but deploy only those mentioned in web.xml

Comment: The best way would be to intercept opening of and `/WEB-INF/web.xml` and append servlet mappings there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @tair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: https://github.com/tsabirgaliev/tomcat-agent

### Quick and dirty solution for Tomcat 8.0

```java
public class Agent {
    public static class Target {

        public static final String GLOBAL_SERVLET_PATTERN = "/globalServlet";
        public static final String GLOBAL_SERVLET_NAME = "globalServlet";

        public boolean intercept(
                @SuperCall Callable<Boolean> zuper
                , @Argument(0) InputSource source
                , @Argument(1) Object dest
                , @Argument(2) boolean fragment
                , @This Object self
        ) {
            try {
                boolean ok = zuper.call();

                if (!fragment) {
                    Method getServletMappings = dest.getClass().getMethod("getServletMappings");
                    Map<String, String> mappings = (Map<String, String>)getServletMappings.invoke(dest);

                    if (!mappings.containsKey(GLOBAL_SERVLET_PATTERN)) {
                        ClassLoader loader = self.getClass().getClassLoader();

                        Class<?> servletDefClass = Class
                        .forName("org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.ServletDef", true, loader);

                        Object servletDef = servletDefClass.newInstance();

                        servletDefClass.getMethod("setServletClass", String.class)
                        .invoke(servletDef, "io.tair.myagent.GlobalServlet");

                        servletDefClass.getMethod("setServletName", String.class)
                        .invoke(servletDef, GLOBAL_SERVLET_NAME);

                        dest.getClass().getMethod("addServlet", servletDefClass)
                        .invoke(dest, servletDef);

                        dest.getClass().getMethod("addServletMapping", String.class, String.class)
                        .invoke(dest, GLOBAL_SERVLET_PATTERN, GLOBAL_SERVLET_NAME);
                    }

                }

                return ok;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(named("org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser"))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader) ->
                builder.method (
                    named("parseWebXml")
                    .and(takesArgument(0, InputSource.class))
                )
                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new Target()))
            )
            .installOn(inst);

    }
}
```

The idea is to intercept the calls to `org.apache...WebXmlParser#parseWebXml(InputSource, WebXml, boolean)` and add the necessary servlet mappings right after the parsing of web.xml files.

The heavy part is handled by excellent ByteBuddy [1]. For this agent to work you will have to include ByteBuddy classes.

If GlobalServlet is packaged within the agent, you will also have to include ServletApi classes. This for sure can be avoided, but I don't know enough ByteBuffer magic to implement that.

### UPDATE for Tomcat 7.0

The following solution will need jsp-api in addition to servlet-api.

```java
public class Agent {
    public static class Target {

        public static final String GLOBAL_SERVLET_PATTERN = "/globalServlet";
        public static final String GLOBAL_SERVLET_NAME = "globalServlet";

        public void intercept(
                @SuperCall Callable<Void> zuper
                , @This Object self
        ) {
            try {
                Method getServletMappings = self.getClass().getMethod("getServletMappings");
                Map<String, String> mappings = (Map<String, String>)getServletMappings.invoke(self);

                if (!mappings.containsKey(GLOBAL_SERVLET_PATTERN)) {
                    ClassLoader loader = self.getClass().getClassLoader();

                    Class<?> servletDefClass = Class
                            .forName("org.apache.catalina.deploy.ServletDef", true, loader);

                    Object servletDef = servletDefClass.newInstance();

                    servletDefClass.getMethod("setServletClass", String.class)
                            .invoke(servletDef, "io.tair.myagent.GlobalServlet");

                    servletDefClass.getMethod("setServletName", String.class)
                            .invoke(servletDef, GLOBAL_SERVLET_NAME);

                    self.getClass().getMethod("addServlet", servletDefClass)
                            .invoke(self, servletDef);

                    self.getClass().getMethod("addServletMapping", String.class, String.class)
                            .invoke(self, GLOBAL_SERVLET_PATTERN, GLOBAL_SERVLET_NAME);
                }

                zuper.call();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(named("org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml"))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader) ->
                builder.method (
                    named("configureContext")
                )
                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new Target()))
            )
            .installOn(inst);

    }
}
```

[1] http://bytebuddy.net/

Comment: In my case, the globalServlet is packaged along with the agent and that is the problem. I cannot include the servlet-api jar in agent because tomcat complains and doesn't load the actual webapp and if I don't include, then the agent complains of no-class-def-found error.

Comment: @Vikdor I'm not sure I understood your comment properly.. I included servlet-api with my agent, and Tomcat started and works fine so far. Do you have some specific issues with inclusion of the servlet-api?

Comment: Yes, my agent is a maven project and the jar is generated using maven-assembly-plugin. With servlet-api dependency in "provided" scope, the maven-assembly generates a simple jar that only has agent specific classes. When I specify this agent in CATALINA_OPTS using -javaagent:/path/to/agent.jar, the jar fails to load because it cannot find javax.servlet.HttpServlet class. With servlet-api dependency in normal scope, the maven-assembly generates a jar that has classes from servlet-api.jar. With this agent jar, the agent is loaded, but the application fails to start in the tomcat container.

Comment: I am using tomcat-7.0.50.

Comment: @Vikdor let me test my solution with Tomcat 7

Comment: @Vikdor yes, including servlet-api breaks `DigesterFactory.idFor(..)` method

Comment: @Vikdor fixed by including also `tomcat-jsp-api` into agent :)

Comment: @Vikdor + some modifications to adapt for Tomcat 7.0